# MYSQL/PHP Shifting order of objects up or down while maintaining numerical order

Tags: php, mysql, counting

I have table that holds objects, it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `post_objects` (
  `id` mediumint(7) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` mediumint(7) NOT NULL,
  `object_data` text,
  `object_order` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `created` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The `object_order` column tracks the numerical order of the objects and is used to sort when the objects are pulled. It maintains 1, 2, 3, 4, ad infinitum depending on how many objects are assigned to a `post_id`.

**The Problem:**

From my PHP I want to be able to move objects up or down incrementally by one. For example, move the object with and order of 3 to the 2 position, and have the remaining objects reorder themselves so as to still maintain 1, 2, 3, 4...

**What I've Tried:**

The current function is not giving me the expected result. Currently if I move the last position down, it is not renumbering correctly.  Here is the latest attempt:

```
// Shift given object order by one in given direction.
function objectOrderShift ($object_id, $shift_type) {
    $post_id = getParentPostId($object_id);
    $current_object_order_value = getObjectOrderValue($object_id);
    switch ($shift_type) {
        case 'up':
            $new_object_order_value = $current_object_order_value - 1;
            break;
        case 'down':
            $new_object_order_value = $current_object_order_value + 1;
            break;
    }

    // Update new object id to new order value (*THERE WILL BE TWO ENTRIES WITH THE SAME ORDER NUMBER*)
    $sql = "UPDATE post_objects SET object_order = :new_object_order_value WHERE id = :object_id";
    $stmt = db::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->bindParam(':object_id', $object_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $stmt->bindParam(':new_object_order_value', $new_object_order_value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    //set starting order value
    $object_order_value = 1;
    // Run select for all objects edit as needed
    $sql = "SELECT id, object_order FROM post_objects WHERE post_id = :post_id ORDER BY object_order ASC";
    $stmt = db::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
     $stmt->bindParam(':post_id', $post_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach ($results as $row) {
        $flux_object_id = $row['id'];  // holder for other object_id's from SELECT query

        if($flux_object_id == $object_id) {
            // This is the already altered object_id, skip entry and ++ value
            $object_order_value++;
        }
        $sql = "UPDATE post_objects SET object_order = :object_order_value, created = NOW() WHERE id = :flux_object_id";
        $stmt = db::getInstance()->prepare($sql);
         $stmt->bindParam(':flux_object_id', $flux_object_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $stmt->bindParam(':object_order_value', $object_order_value, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $object_order_value++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in a single query. And since you're only shifting by a single place, you only need to update 2 rows: the object you're moving, and the row before or after it in object order.

To shift an object down:

```
UPDATE post_objects AS p1
JOIN post_objects AS p2 ON p1.object_order IN (p2.object_order, p2.object_order - 1)
SET p1.object_order = 
    CASE WHEN p1.id = p2.id THEN p1.object_order - 1
         ELSE p1.object_order + 1
    END
WHERE p2.id = :object_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution. I don't completely understand the query just yet but trying to run it as is results in: 
`...You have an error in your SQL syntax; check ... for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE p2.id = '50''`

Comment: I left out `END`.